# Mailgun : Cancel queued emails

Tags: php, email, queue, mailgun, mail-queue

I am using mailgun API to send emails. By mistake I called a function that queued thousands of emails in Mailgun.

Is there a way to Cancel/Clear the queue?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to cancel a Mailgun queue.

Comment: How did you solved the problem?

Comment: @waterkinq Not able to solve it

Comment: @NishitModi thank you for your clear answer :) Thats right. Unfortunately, I have sent 889K emails and could not do anything. As a person who does such a mistake, my suggestion is that the best way to do in such problems is to open a support ticket from Mailgun. They are purging it. you cannot do anything More.

Comment: Mailgun has an **official solution** to handle this situation: [https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012487654-How-can-I-delete-messages-from-the-queue-](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012487654-How-can-I-delete-messages-from-the-queue-).

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to exist an easy way through the API, except contacting Mailgun Support.

On the other hand, I found a handy workaround that might work for your case: add the recipients in the Bounced Recipients temporarily (Suppressions) so when the time comes, email will not be sent and marked as failed/bounced from Mailgun.

When all of the emails you wanted disappeared are marked as bounced, you can remove recipients from bounces list.

Hope this helps

ps: I know it's an old thread but, mistakes are made all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I've sent an email to 150 recipients to the mailgun servers and used BatchMessage and setDeliveryTime() to schedule it for the next day at 7 AM, there's currently no way to cancel this message if I decide later, before the set time, to cancel the job.

This could be fixed by getting a return hash value when using finalize() which then could be used with a new function deleteMessageQueue(return hash value) that will cancel the job.

The canceled message still counts the email credits used, of course.

Answer (score 0):

rather than Bouncing the address, you can tag your emails and then just unsubscribe the address from the specific tag.